# plugin Fabric Android Studio not found import com.crashlytics & io.fabric

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

On my new project i would like to integrate Crashlytics from Fabric.io

I've already installed Fabric on others projects without issue, one project with the tutorial here : https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

And on the other project, I've using the plugin Fabric integrated into Android Studio (picture) [image]

here's the problem :

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class UILApplication extends Application {   

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());  // Fabric not found
    }    
}


Error:(6, 31) error: package com.crashlytics.android does not exist
Error:(7, 29) error: package io.fabric.sdk.android does not exist
Error:(20, 31) error: cannot find symbol class Crashlytics
Error:(20, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable Fabric
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

my build.gradle (Project) :

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
       // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } THIS LINE FORGOTTEN
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
   // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 24
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "agemos.testkalman1"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"            
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'

    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.2.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
//    // Crashlytics Fabric io
//    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3@aar') {
//        transitive = true;
//    }

}
```

I've change compileSdkVersion 23 to 24 but nothing has changed, someone had this problem  ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

---

I've forgot one line

Now it works ! sorry for the inconvenience ^^'

Comment: post your root and app level gradle files. You must haven't followed steps correctly

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' and Gradle Version 2.14

Comment: Please post your build gradle files you followed from tutorial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

It appears that you've commented out all initialization of Fabric in your build.gradle? If you un-comment the lines below, that should work.

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }


// Crashlytics Fabric io
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

The full build.gradle would have [all of the following changes](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
```

Comment: This is outdated! Can you please update your answer with recent developments?

Comment: It's not something I work on currently, so I'll defer to the current experts to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**clear and Rebuild and Restart Android Studio Its Working**

[image]

**build.gradle project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }


    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.holostik.ozoneoverseas"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    // TODO FCM
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'     // TODO Previous working
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
//    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0"

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    //TODO camera Crop dependency working
//    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar')

//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'

//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    //    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'           // Works here
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.1'           // Works here
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}




/*buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}*/
// TODO FCM
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // TODO FCM add auto in Bottom  When Google Service Add uncomment this

//dependencies {
//    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
//    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//}



crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="1864e6d3e59158a5206d2d073e7e14c7ad811cbd" />
```

**Splash Activity**

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());
 }
```